# What the error in my code. I try to use array in class but getting logical error

Tags: c++

I try to make an array and take input and then simply showing the output on the screen but uses classes and objects, Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class array{
    int ar[], n;
    public:
        void input();
        int display();
}obj;
void array::input(){
    cout<<"Enter item size: ";
    cin>>n;
    int ar[n]={};
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<"Enter value at index "<<i<<" : ";
        cin>>ar[i];
    }

}
int array::display(){
    cout<<"You Entered: ";

    for(int i=0 ; i<n; i++){
        cout<<ar[i];
    }
}
int main(){

    obj.input();
    obj.display();

}
```

In the sample run, I entered 1 and 2 and I am expected to get 1 and 2.

Comment: `int ar[]` does this actually compile? What is the size of the array?

Comment: this program is working, but give me a logical error only, when I entered 1 and 2. it outputs 2 and 0.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Are you joking? [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f25a14b4045efc0) _warning: ISO C++ forbids flexible array member 'ar' [-Wpedantic]_

Comment: Variable Length Arrays are *not* a feature of *standard* C++. You want `std::vector`.

Comment: If you got this compiled then you "exploited" a proprietary extension of your C++ compiler. However, you still have a storage problem with `ar[]`. Please, have a look at [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). That's _the_ "dynamic array" of C++.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for pointing out. how to fix this compiler issue.

Comment: I did my very best.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems in your code.

First `int ar[]` should not compile. I get the following error:

```
prog.cc:4:12: error: ISO C++ forbids flexible array member 'ar' [-Wpedantic]
     int ar[], n;
            ^
```

Next, in `array::input()` you create a completely new array `int ar[n]={};` which is also not valid c++. Array sizes must be compiletime constants. Moreover, this array shadows the member and is unrelated to it (apart from having the same name). So this `ar` is gone once you return from the method. You never write anything into the member `ar`.

If you dont know the size in advance you should use a `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class array{
    std::vector<int> ar;
    public:
        void input();
        int display();
};
void array::input(){
    std::cout << "Enter item size: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    ar.resize(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        std::cout << "Enter value at index " << i << " : ";
        std::cin >> ar[i];
    }

}
int array::display(){
    std::cout<<"You Entered: ";

    for(int i=0 ; i<n; ++i){
        std::cout << ar[i];
    }
}
int main() {
    array obj;    
    obj.input();
    obj.display();    
}
```

PS: read here why `using namespace std;` is bad practice: [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO [user463035818s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55655970/7478597) is sufficient, but for all that OP asked me

> how to fix this compiler issue.

The recommended fix would be by design i.e. like shown in [user463035818s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55655970/7478597).

So, I want to elaborate how to fix the sample code of OP (with "minimal" changes). That might make obvious why [user463035818s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55655970/7478597) is the better one. (I repeated the link three times – it should be clear to everybody that I consider this as the better solution.)

The actual compiler error (or warning or feature accepted by compiler extension):
OP used `int ar[]` a C array as class member without denoting the size.

This is called [Flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) but it is a C99 feature (not supported by the C++ standard).

The linked Wikipedia article provides a nice example:

```
struct vectord {
    size_t len;
    double arr[]; // the flexible array member must be last
};
```

To be clear, flexible array members don't provide automatic allocation. They just represent an array of arbitrary length. The programmer is responsible to grant sufficient storage for that array. Hence even in C, and with the resp. syntax adjustments, this code would have been broken.

Some C++ compilers adopt features from C as (proprietary) extension. That's the reason that OP got responses ranging from "On my side, it works."<sup>1</sup> to "This is a compiler error." However, I would consider usage of such extensions as bad style in general. With different compiler settings or a different compiler, this might not work anymore.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This is not the only issue of OPs code. "It works" might be merely bad luck. OPs code has [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior/4105123#4105123). One kind of Undefined Behavior is "It works" which is not the best one because programmer might believe that the code is fine.</sub>

---

A lot of higher level languages (Java, C#, Python) tries to cover memory allocation and storage management "under the hood" completely because it's not quite easy to make this always correct and consider every edge case sufficiently. This might cause an additional performance impact for the administration of memory. In C and C++, the programmer has ful control over memory allocation. It's both a blessing and a curse.
The standard library of C++ provides a variety of tools to make programmers allocation life easier.

For dynamic arrays, *the* tool of choice is the template class [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It provides an overloaded `operator[]` which allows that it can be accessed just like an array. It provides methods like `reserve()` and `resize()`. The storage is internally managed.

I would *strongly recommend to use `std::vector`* but there is also the possibility to do it using [`new[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and [`delete[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete).

---

For this, the `class array` might look as follows:

```
class array {
    int *ar; // a raw pointer for storage
    int n; // the current size of array
  public:
    int display();
```

`int*` and `int` are [plain old data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/146589/7478597) types → implicit construction leaving them uninitialized. So, there really should be defined at least a default constructor.

```
    array(): ar(nullptr), n(0) { }
```

The `input()` method has to ensure proper storage.

```
    void input()
    {
      // release old memory (if there is one)
      delete[] ar; ar = nullptr; n = 0;
      // input
      std::cout << "Enter item size: ";
      std::cin >> n;
      if (n <= 0) return;
      ar = new int[n];
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Enter value at index " << i << ": ";
        std::cin >> ar[i];
      }
    }
```

When an instance of `class array` is deleted it should release the internal storage. Otherwise, the allocated memory pointed by `ar` will be orphaned and lost until process is terminated by OS. Such lost memory is called [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

```
    ~array() { delete[] ar; }
```

Please, note that calling `delete[]` (or `delete`) with a `nullptr` is valid. Hence, no extra `if (ar)` is needed.

Finally, we have to obey the [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). The compiler generates implicitly copy constructor and copy assignment operator which will copy the `class array` members by value. Copying a pointer by value does not mean that the contents (it points to) is copied. It just means copy the pointer (address value). Hence, an (accidental, unintended) copy of `class array` could result in two instances of `class array` which members `ar` point to the same memory. Once, one of them deletes that memory, the `ar` of the other becomes dangling i.e. points to released memory. (Bad!) If the other instance is destroyed also it will `delete[] ar` again. This is double deleting which is prohibited. (Bad again!)

One option could be to define copy constructor and copy assignment to handle this appropriately by making a deep copy of `ar` contents (with another `new[]`). However, if copy is not intended, an alternative is to just explixitly prohibit copy for `class array`:

```
    array(const array&) = delete;
    array& operator=(const array&) = delete;
};
```

Putting this althogether in `array.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>

class array {
    int *ar; // a raw pointer for storage
    int n; // the current size of array
  public:
    array(): ar(nullptr), n(0) { }
    ~array() { delete[] ar; }
    array(const array&) = delete;
    array& operator=(const array&) = delete;

    void input();
    void display();
};

void array::input()
{
  // release old memory (if there is one)
  delete[] ar; ar = nullptr; n = 0;
  // input
  std::cout << "Enter item size: ";
  std::cin >> n;
  if (n <= 0) return;
  ar = new int[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Enter value at index " << i << ": ";
    std::cin >> ar[i];
  }
}

void array::display()
{
  std::cout << "You Entered: ";
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    std::cout << ar[i];
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  array obj;
  obj.input();
  obj.display();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic array.cc && ./a.out
Enter item size: 1↲
Enter value at index 0: 2↲
You Entered: 2

$
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b85c8d8e294596fa)</kbd>

---

The last sentence in OPs question is a bit unclear for me (although I assume it's just bad worded):

> In the sample run, I entered 1 and 2 and I am expected to get 1 and 2.

Either input is `2 1 2` then output is `1 2`.
Or input is `1 2` then output is `2`.

Please note that `array::input()` expects first input of `array::n` but `array::display()` doesn't output `array::n`.